# Problem to get some values from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the values ​​from json
estimatedDeliveryDate and amount but I have found errors and difficulties to get these values, I tried several ways but none managed to extract the result, if anyone has any tips on how I can do this thank you, follow the code below in javascript plus json for the extraction

```
var json = {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://www.usereserva.com/ccstoreui/v1/shippingMethods"
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "shippingGroupId": "0",
            "shippingAddress": {
                "computedState": [
                    "RS"
                ],
                "lastName": " asdas",
                "country": "BR",
                "numero": "",
                "city": "Erechim",
                "prefix": "",
                "dynamicProperties": [

                ],
                "postalCode": "99711268",
                "jobTitle": "",
                "companyName": "",
                "county": "",
                "predefinedAddressTypes": [

                ],
                "isDefaultAddress": false,
                "suffix": "",
                "type": "",
                "selectedCountry": "BR",
                "computedCountry": [
                    "BR"
                ],
                "selectedAddressTypes": [

                ],
                "complemento": "",
                "populateShippingMethods": true,
                "alias": "",
                "addressDescriptionComputed": "Rua Ernesto Pagnoncelli, Koller, Erechim - RS",
                "state": "RS",
                "isDefaultShippingAddress": false,
                "email": "teste4@hotmail.com",
                "selectedState": "RS",
                "state_ISOCode": "BR-RS",
                "isDefaultBillingAddress": false,
                "types": [

                ],
                "address3": "Koller",
                "address2": "",
                "address1": "Rua Ernesto Pagnoncelli",
                "addressType": [

                ],
                "defaultCountryCode": "BR",
                "isTypeModified": false,
                "firstName": "teste",
                "phoneNumber": "(54) 984354020",
                "computedDefaultShipping": false,
                "computedDefaultBilling": false,
                "repositoryId": "",
                "recipient": "teste asdas",
                "faxNumber": "",
                "computedAddressType": [

                ],
                "middleName": "",
                "referencia": ""
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "commerceItemId": "ci17672126437481",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "productId": "0053394",
                    "catRefId": "005339401402"
                }
            ],
            "shippingMethods": [
                {
                    "shippingCalculator": "priceRange",
                    "eligibleForProductWithSurcharges": false,
                    "isExternallyPriced": false,
                    "ranges": [
                        {
                            "amount": 0.0,
                            "high": null,
                            "low": 0.0,
                            "repositoryId": "100001"
                        }
                    ],
                    "associatedPriceListGroups": [
                        {
                            "repositoryId": "real"
                        }
                    ],
                    "displayName": "Retire em Loja",
                    "description": "Retire em Loja",
                    "allSites": true,
                    "sites": [

                    ],
                    "taxCode": null,
                    "type": 0,
                    "shippingGroupType": "hardgoodShippingGroup",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "displaySequence": 0,
                    "repositoryId": "100001",
                    "excludedCategoriesShippingCharge": [

                    ],
                    "isFallback": false,
                    "id": "100001",
                    "shipToLocations": [
                        {
                            "repositoryId": "100001"
                        }
                    ],
                    "excludedCategories": [

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "shippingCalculator": "external",
                    "eligibleForProductWithSurcharges": false,
                    "estimatedDeliveryDateGuaranteed": false,
                    "internationalDutiesTaxesFees": "0",
                    "ranges": [
                        {
                            "amount": 19.87,
                            "high": 1.7976931348623157E308,
                            "low": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "displayName": "Transporte Padrão",
                    "taxCode": "GT987",
                    "shippingGroupType": "hardgoodShippingGroup",
                    "estimatedDeliveryDate": "2020-08-21T17:21:05Z",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "deliveryDays": 12,
                    "repositoryId": "Transporte Padrão",
                    "carrierId": "ON"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

var deliveryDate = json["items"];
var deliveryPrice = json.items;
console.log(JSON.stringify(deliveryDate));
console.log(JSON.stringify(deliveryPrice));

// I NEED GET THAT JSON
//console.log(json.items[1].shippingMethods[2].estimatedDeliveryDate)
//console.log( json.items[1].shippingMethods[2].ranges[1].amount)
```

Comment: That is an object literal, not JSON.

Comment: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `I have found errors and difficulties` you need to be way more specific. What errors? What difficulties?

Comment: `json.items[0].shippingMethods[1].estimatedDeliveryDate`, but you might want to do some traversing here, it's built of arrays..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are zero-indexed, which means that index `0` is the first element, not `1`.

```
console.log(json.items[0].shippingMethods[1].estimatedDeliveryDate)
console.log(json.items[0].shippingMethods[1].ranges[0].amount)
```